# Where do I store and how can I show on GUI kind of a volatile "global" variable?

Tags: android

In my android app there're an Activity and Service. The service is periodically doing some jobs in background, let's say, once in a 10 seconds -- pretty frequently. The service is always in background even when the Activity is closed/destroyed. And the services has a variable for saving a result of its calculations.

I want to display that variable on GUI and make the GUI show the current value of it in real time. The service, I'm not sure yet, but will be a normal service, not Intent Service due to some reason.

How can I show that variable on my GUI in real time? What's the approach, where should I begin? Is it enough to store it only in the service or should I also store it in more permanent storage as well such as Sqlite or SharedPreferences?

On startup or boot I want to reset the variable. So it's zero.

Comment: *The service, I'm not sure yet, but will be a normal service, not Intent Service due to some reason.* the reason should be that intentservices are meant to be a one time operation kind of service, like do an operation once and then kill itself.

Comment: @TimCastelijns, and?

Comment: Just saying. I thought you weren't sure why to pick a 'regular' service

Comment: @TimCastelijns, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a **foreground notification** (or probably simple "not autocancelable" notification) and update it's text every time you receive new data at your service.

If you also need to submit that data to activities you can use **BroadcastReceiver**

Answer (score 1):

Because your Activity is not always running, and on startup you probably want to show the last-fetched value there, I would save the value in the SharedPreferences. When your Activity starts, you can retrieve the value, and you can also add an OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener. This will make sure that every time the Service finds and stores a new value, the Activity is notified.

Comment: Another reason to store it in sharedprefs is that while it's easy to store the value inside the service (e.g. a static variable) it can be lost in cases the OS decides to kill the server. The server will be restarted, but the value will be lost/null temporarily then

Comment: **on startup you probably want to show the last-fetched value there** -- nope, on startup -- zero.

Comment: the question is also how to update GUI to show the variable? Are you sure it's a good idea to save the variable in SharedPrefe-s every 10 seconds (might be even more frequently)?

Comment: @MariusKavansky Saving values in the preferences is no heavy work, it's okay to do that often. As for the startup part, you can choose to not show the value in the preferences. The Activity will get notified the next time the value changes.

Comment: even updating a variable(s) in SharedPreferences every 1 second isn't heavy and pretty much ok?

Comment: @MariusKavansky I'm sorry, I don't know where the boundary is for that between 'ok' and 'too much'. I would say that every 10 seconds is okay, but I don't know for every 1 second.